# How to select top 5 users

Tags: php, sql

I built "Competition Entrances" and I have this table.

> 'entries'
>
> > https://gyazo.com/f536c8a38ddf45ef6e5d79cc9814a61f

now I want to show the top 5 users, have the most entries.

badaway, i now that i can make a new table and count the entries for every-user, but its not better i think.

Can anyone here help me with the sql syntax?
thanks a lot!

Comment: show us your sql query

Comment: what you mean? i have no sql query..

Comment: @UnderPhp Then create one.  SO is not a free coding service.  You post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Eric but i dont know how to write this query. I just need to select the most 5 popular user ID in my table. Who gots the most entries.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best with mysql syntax, but it should look something like this.

`SELECT userId, COUNT(userId)
 FROM [tableName]
 LIMIT 5
 ORDER BY COUNT(userId) DESC`

Comment: thanks but your query is just counting the numbers of userId. I'm trying to show the top 5 users with the most enteris.

Comment: I would expect the result of that query to be: 15,3  7,2  17,2.  Which tells me that user 15 has made 3 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this, I'm supposing your table name is "entries"

```
SELECT userId, SUM(1) FROM entries ORDER BY SUM(1) GROUP BY userID DESC LIMIT 5;
```